# Check if an item isset in a decoded JSON string

Tags: php, json, twitter

I'm working on a module which loads data from Twitter's user_timeline REST API.  Once I have the JSON decoded, I do a foreach statement in my PHP to get each of the returned tweets.  I'm currently having an issue checking for items under the retweeted_status portion of the JSON string.  The JSON I'm calling is:

```
"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=".$count."&include_rts=1&screen_name=".$uname.""
```

retweeted_status is only returned if a tweet is a retweet.  So, for example, if the tweet is a retweet, I want to return the original tweet's text, not the retweet.  I've tried this code:

```
if(isset($t->retweeted_status->text)) {
    $tweet = $t->retweeted_status->text;
} else {
    $tweet = $t->text;
}
```

Using the above code, when retweeted_status is NOT returned, isset is still true for all objects after the first time the isset is returned true.

What I need is a conditional within my foreach that will properly check for items under retweeted_status (since the retweeted datapoint is disabled and has been for some time) and reset the check to false if retweeted_status is not present.

Any suggestions?

Comment: i dont exectly understand what you want to do but i think u should look in the direction of putting an array or boolian before the foreach loop and use this to save the status but if you make it more clear what you are trying maby i can help more

Comment: Within my module, I'm trying to pull information from the retweeted_status portion of the JSON string, if it exists, and if it does not then the information is returned from a different portion of the JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has excellent JSON support built-in, so there's no need to manually grokk through the JSON string to find out whether or not the object it represents has a given property. Just do

```
$twitterObj = json_decode( $responseTextFromTwitterAPI [, true ] );
```

with the second param = `true` if the JSON string represents an associative array, false if it's a "plain" (integer-indexed) one. (You'll want to check Twitter's docs to find out.) Then your checks should amount to something like (I'm not familiar with Twitter's API spec...):

```
foreach ( $twitterObj as $tweet ) {
    if ( isset( $tweet['retweeted_status'] ) ) {
        // Retweet
    } else {
        // Original
    }
    // Do stuff...
}
```

EDIT:

This works for me:

```
$obj = json_decode( $jsonFromTwitter, true );
foreach ( $obj as $o ) {
if ( isset($o['retweeted_status']) ) {
   echo $o['retweeted_status']['text'];
} else {
    echo $o['text];
}
```

You should be able to get where you want from there, right?

Comment: I added the true param to my json_decode, and when I do a var_dump for isset($t->retweeted_status), I still receive trues where it should be false.  When I do the check as isset($t['retweeted_status']), I receive the "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" PHP error.

Comment: "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=20&include_rts=1&screen_name=mbabker"

As of this moment, the 4th object is a retweet.

Comment: Hmm... With the code from the edit, if I extract just my JSON retreival from my helper and run it, it works.  So, something in my code is changing the JSON from an array to an object.  The helper's located at http://tinyurl.com/TDBhelper.  Any suggestions on what could be converting it?